# How to add to `date` four days?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var $date = $('#field').val();
 date = get_date_from_string($date);
 alert(date); //Sun Feb 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

How to add to `date` four days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var today= new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 4);
```

Comment: Thanks. Hmm It does not work in my example

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function

```
var $date = $('#field').val();
newdate = addDays1($date,4)
alert(newdate);

      function addDays1(date1,days)
             {  
                 var date = date1;  
                 var d  = date.substring(0,2);  
                 var m = date.substring(3,5);
                 var y  = date.substring(6,10); 
                 var tdays=parseFloat(d)+parseInt(days);

                 while(tdays!=0)    
                    {
                        var dmax = caldays(m,y);
                        if(dmax>=tdays)     
                        { 
                            var day = tdays;
                            tdays =0;       
                        }       
                        else        
                        { 
                            var day =parseInt(tdays)-parseInt(dmax);            
                            var tdays= day;                     
                            var Month = ((m*10)/10)+1;                      
                            var dmax = caldays(Month,y);
                            if(Month>12)            
                            {               
                                m =parseInt(Month)-12;              
                                day = days;             
                                y = parseInt(y)+1;              
                                if(days<dmax)               
                                tdays=0;            
                            }           
                            else                
                            m =parseInt(Month);             
                                y = parseInt(y);                
                                day = tdays;                
                            if(day<=dmax)               
                                 tdays=0;               
                        }    
                        }       
                        if(tdays==0)    
                        {                
                        if(day<10)                
                         {          
                            day="0"+day;         
                         }       
                         if(m<10)                
                          {                 
                              m=(m*10)/10;          
                              m="0"+m;                  
                          }              
                           var str=day+"/"+m+"/"+y;                
                            return str;             
           }    
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code.

```
var today = new Date();
var newDay = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+4));
```